# Fresnel has to be above 1?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor

When I'm doing something with metal node groups, I noticed something with the Fresnel node. When I set below 1, I get a strange result, not the result that really reflects but only a part or none reflects(or refracts). I'm using Blender 2.73 by the way.

Comment: This is correct, the index of refraction of any given material is pretty much always above 1. Values below 1 will be weird (as you have noticed)

Comment: IOR values less than 1 are physically impossible, so you will get strange results.

Comment: Then. how to create ior values that are lower than 1

Comment: But the IOR of gold is 0.47?